# How to convert .jtl to .xml file in Jmeter

Tags: xml, jmeter

I have an existing .jtl file, and I want to convert this file to .xml using Jmeter.

Can anyone help how to convert this file in Jmeter?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Did you have tried something already? Can you post some code so far?

Comment: Yes. I did below sample code but is not working properly:

I added a JSR223 sample with below script:

def file = new File('file.jtl').readLines()

def file2 = new File('file2.xml')
file2.withWriter { writer -> file.each {line->writer.writeLine(line)}}

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have existing [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) in CSV format and want to convert it to XML you can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) like:

   ```
   FilterResults.bat --output-file result.xml --input-file result.jtl --save-as-xml true
   ```
2. If you want to switch JMeter to save its results in XML going forward - add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   ```

   More information: [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
3. If you want both XML and CSV you can add a Listener, i.e. Simple Data Writer and choose what, where and how to store there:

   [image]

   More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri,  I tried the above solution (#1) and was able to successfully convert the .jtl file into .xml. However, in the .xml file, some fields are added that are not present in .jtl and some fields are missing. For example,  in jtl file, the fields are response code, responsemessage and URL. After converting to xml file, The URL field is missing and some fields like timestamp that are not present in jtl are added on .xml.  Where Ican I configure the output so that the same fields will only display on xml file. Thanks